# Use Dism v10 of ADK on Srv2012r2 inside a script

Tags: powershell, dism

What I Want to achive: I want to update a batch of wim-files via a scheduled task. Therfore I mount the wims, add the update-packages and dismount the wims. So far no problem via the dism-module included in PoSh4 on Windowsserver 2012r2.

**Problem:**

This does not work with wim-files of Windows 10, because the dism-version used via the module is lower (6.3.x) than the necessary version of the wim-image (10.x).

**What I tried:**

1) Remove the stock dism-module via `remove-module dism` and import the dism-module via `Import-Module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM'`. Running `Get-WindowsEdition -Online -verbose` still delivers dism version 6.3.x

2) Use `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM\dism.exe` in the script via `$env:path` or via `-f` and `&`. In the fist attempt, dism didnt get the arguments I tried to apply. In the second attempt, dism does not get recognized as a command.

There must be some thing I overlooked, but I cant figure it out.

How does the code need to look like? Args could be e.g.:

`$mountpath = 'd:\autoupdating' 
$package = 'D:\updates\whatever.cab' 
$dismcommands = "/image:$mountpath /add-package /packagepath:$package`

**Solution:**

PoSh or DISM has heavy problems when getting `$dismcommands` like I wanted it. DISM does not recognize the string as available commands. You can bypass this easiely by going
`DISM.exe "/image:$mountpath /add-package /packagepath:$package"` which works without a problem.
Furthermore you need to modify the `$env:Path` variable to target `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM\`. I've done this by backing up `$env:Path`, resetting it and restoring it after I finished working on an WIn10.wim.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use this code with Windows 8.1 64bit to service Win 10 wim (after installing DISM from the newest ADK of course):

```
import-module "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM"

$env:Path = "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM;$env:Path"
```

Use in each new session.